# Calling Java Methods in XSLT

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

Trying to generat a random number with the help of Java UUID class.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns:uuid="java:java.util.UUID">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="uid" select="uuid:randomUUID()"/>
<ClientPK><xsl:value-of select="$uid"/></ClientPK>
```

**Error**

```
Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named {java:java.util.UUID}randomUUID().
  Note that direct calls to Java methods are not available under Saxon-HE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensibility, if you want to use Saxon 9 and have that feature (called reflexive extension functions) you need a license for PE or EE.

Comment: so, is there no other way to call Java functions during an XSLT transformation than  paying Saxon's (high) licence fees?

Comment: It depends on the XSLT processor you want to use, there is the XSLT 1.0 processor Xalan which I think has similar mechanisms to call into Java, there is Saxon 6.5, also an XSLT 1.0 processor, then there are various versions of Saxon 9, Saxon 9.1 B was the latest version of the open source product to allow to call directly into Java. Since 9.2 if you want to what the feature matrix http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensibility calls "reflexive extension functions" then you need PE or EE, however the open source HE supports a new feature called "integrated extension functions".

Comment: thanks for the great info.  I was using Saxon 6.5, but found that when you update Java to version 8, there are bugs with the old Saxon that can only be remedied by updating :(  I will check out what that new feature of HE is all about