# XSLT processor to call Java methods

Tags: java, xslt

Extension of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004719/calling-java-methods-in-xslt/).

I am currently using open source `Saxon HE` which does not support calling java methods.
 Is there any open source solution for this problem? Due to the budget constraints I don't think I will be allowed to purchase license for `Saxon PE/EE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of for XSLT 2.0.  Processors such as [Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/) support extension functions in the way you require but only for XSLT 1.0.

Alternatively you could try an older version of Saxon (e.g. Saxon-B, scroll down to "older products" on http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I was using `Apache Software Foundation (Xalan XSLTC)` before but then moved to Saxon because `Xalan` did not support `currentDateTime()`. Do you want me to move back to `Xalan`?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav or you could try an older Saxon, before the HE/PE/EE split.